# Application continues to run when the device is connected to XCODE and debug mode. But it will not continue when it is not connected to xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, background, bluetooth

I am creating a application that will continue running on back ground.
When the device is connected to the MAC and debugging, but when I disconnect and run the application standalone, it will finish in 10min. Is there any setting or my codings are wrong?

My code is appdeledate.h is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>


@class TashouNoEnViewController;

@interface TashouNoEnAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,GKSessionDelegate,GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    TashouNoEnViewController *viewController;
    GKSession *mySession;
    IBOutlet UITextField *messageTextField;
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TashouNoEnViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end
```

appdelegate.M is

```
#import "TashouNoEnAppDelegate.h"
#import "TashouNoEnViewController.h"
#define kSessionID @"_tashounoen"

@implementation TashouNoEnAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
//=_window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize navigationController=_navigationController;

NSString *message102;

NSString* a_home_dir;
NSString* a_doc_dir;
NSString* a_path;
NSString *switchcheck;
NSInteger myselfint;
NSInteger swithchcheckint;
NSInteger runcount;
NSInteger runcount2;
NSInteger totalruncount;
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
NSTimer *caallTimer;
NSTimer *caallTimer2;
 NSString *message100;
 NSString *message200;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
 /**
    NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");
    // NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSAssert(backgroundTaskIdentifer == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);
    backgroundTaskIdentifer = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        //  NSLog(@"expired!");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTaskIdentifer != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [app endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifer];
                backgroundTaskIdentifer = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];
    **/
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    runcount=0;
    totalruncount=0;
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
   caallTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(CAALL2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    void (^handler)(void)  = ^{
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    };
   bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:handler];
    [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{


         bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:handler];
        [caallTimer invalidate];
        caallTimer = nil;

        caallTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(CAALL2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


    }];

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{


    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{


    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{


    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate");
}

- (void)session:(GKSession *)session connectionWithPeerFailed:(NSString *)peerID withError:(NSError *)error {
}

- (void)session:(GKSession *)session didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

- (void)session:(GKSession *)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID {

    NSError *error;
    if(![mySession acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&error]) {
    } else {

    }
}


-(void)CAALL2

{


            [mySession disconnectFromAllPeers];
            [mySession release];
            mySession = nil;
            mySession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:kSessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
            mySession.delegate = self;
            [mySession setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
            mySession.available = YES;

caallTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:500 target:self selector:@selector(CAALL2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  //  if (totalruncount<21){

  //  }

}
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {
    switch (state) {
        case GKPeerStateAvailable:
            NSLog(@"GKPeerStateAvailable");
            [mySession connectToPeer:peerID withTimeout:31.0f];
            break;
        case GKPeerStateUnavailable:
            break;
        case GKPeerStateConnected:
            [self btnSend:peerID];
   break;
        case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
            break;
        case GKPeerStateConnecting:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession:(GKSession *)session context:(void *)context {


    message100 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 //   NSLog(@"frompeerid%@",peer);
 //   NSLog(@"get%@",message100);
    int checkdata = [message100 intValue ];
    if (checkdata==111)
    {
        message100 =@"111";
        UIApplication *app  = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.fireDate  = notificationDate;
        notification.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
        notification.alertBody = message100;
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        [notification release];
    }
    else if (checkdata==110)
    {
        message100 =@"110";
        UIApplication *app  = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.fireDate  = notificationDate;
        notification.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
        notification.alertBody = message100;
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        [notification release];
    }

}

- (void) mySendDataToPeers:(NSData *) data:(NSString *)peerID
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSLog(@"senddata");
    if (mySession)
       NSLog(@"mypeerid%@",peerID);

                [mySession sendData:data toPeers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:peerID] withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}


-(void) btnSend:(NSString *)peerID{

    a_home_dir = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString* a_doc_dir = [a_home_dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    a_path = [a_doc_dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userdata.plist"];

    NSDictionary *plist2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:a_path];
    switchcheck =[plist2 objectForKey:@"switchcheck"];
    swithchcheckint = [switchcheck intValue];

    if(swithchcheckint==1)
    {
        message102 =@"111";
    }
    else if(swithchcheckint==0)
    {
        message102 =@"110";
    }
    //---convert an NSString object to NSData---
    NSData* data;
     [messageTextField setText:message102];
     data = [message102 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self mySendDataToPeers:data:peerID];
}


@end
```

Please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple only allow background processing of an app to occur for 10 minutes (this used to be just 5), unless the app is either music, VOIP or navigational, in which case you will need to specify in your Plist file.

This is why you app stops after 10 minutes, by default Xcode will continue running the app as you are debugging.

Comment: If this answer helped, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it. Thanks.